# The target "GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems" does not exist in the project.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

After installing Visual Studio 2017 RC, and upgrading my ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) project, I am no longer able to publish my project to the file system.

Building the solution works fine, but when I publish I get this error:

```
The target "GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems" does not exist in the project.
```

My project has a reference to an old class library project which is part of the same solution.  The error relates to something it doesn't like in the CSPROJ file for the old class library project, but there's no line number, and the text `GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems` does not exist in the CSPROJ file.

Seems a little cryptic and I'm having trouble identifying the issue.  Has anyone got any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Release Candidate....maybe this is one of the possible bugs of this version....

Comment: @hackerman  Well it seems that you were right, it was a bug!

Answer (score 4):

Quick update: it seems that it's a bug.

I've managed to reproduce the same error with a brand new ASP.NET Core project (.NET Framework), and a new, empty Class Library project.

To replicate:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core Project (.NET Framework), and solution.
2. Add a new Class Library project (.NET Framework) to the solution.
3. Reference the Class Library project in the .NET Core project.
4. Instantiate a class from the Class Library project in the .NET Core project.
5. Rebuild solution - should be fine.
6. Publish the .NET Core project and it throws the error.

Hopefully it will be patched in a future version of Visual Studio 2017 RC / RTM.

Shame, I'll have to go back to Visual Studio 2015 and XPROJ for now.

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue

Comment: Seriously... WTF - still getting this now on all the latest bits from MS...

Answer (score 0):

While it is bug which is already reported on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/869) there is workaround.
Here is what I did:

1. build solution in Release mode(or Debug, what ever you going to
   publish)
2. copy result of build to some folder(ex. bin\Release)
3. copy appsettings.json to same directory
4. copy web.config to same directory
5. modify web.config: set executable and arguments

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean.  Modify web.config how and for what?  What executable and arguments?

Is a relatively simple project just including a class library project as others have mentioned.

Comment: @drewid 4 and 5 is only for IIS hosted applications

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out be a duplicate `ProjectReference` in my `csproj` file, presumably from a merge conflict.

I opened the `csproj` in a text editor, deleted one of the references and it built fine.