# ASP.NET Core publish fails when referencing other project

Tags: asp.net-core, csproj, visual-studio-2017

I'm evaluating Visual Studio 2017 RC for our next project and ran into some issues. For the real project I have a web frontend and a Windows service which use the same shared library for database stuff (and more). All projects are based on the classic .NET Framework 4.6.2. Deployment will be on an on-premise Windows Server.

I created a minimal example as follows:

1. Create a solution with ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) project `MyTest.Web`.
2. Add classic desktop class library `MyTest.Shared`.
3. Reference `MyTest.Shared` in projects `MyTest.Web`.
4. Add code reference to `MyTest.Shared` by adding something like `var c = new MyTest.Shared.Class1()` to the web project.

Developing works like a charm: Building, starting and debugging the project is no problem. But I just can't publish the project. If I use the *Publish* entry from the project's context menu, I get the following error:

> Program.cs(7,21): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'MyTest' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

According to the [full console output](http://pastebin.com/g4frD3KG), there is another build using `csc`, but apparently it doesn't know about my shared project.

If I use `dotnet publish -c Release` to publish the project, I get the following error:

> error MSB4057: The target "GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems" does not exist in the project.

So in this case, the library seems to be referenced and built correctly, but there is another error. ([full console output](http://pastebin.com/nZVbTVya))

I think referencing other projects is something very essential, so why doesn't it work? Did I forget something?

My .NET CLI version is 1.0.0-preview3-004056.

Comment: regarding second problem looks like a bug http://stackoverflow.com/q/40684305/2833802. In general, moving again to csproj and MSBuild (instead of using project.json, where only reference to Nuget package is allowed) is in RC state (that's why it is preview3)

Comment: @Set I'm fully aware that it's an RC, but I hoped that there is a solution or workaround anyway.

Comment: Current issue at github: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/869